# How to by pass case not when exists in teradata?

Tags: teradata

So I have created a table that has the following columns from a transaction table with all customer purchase records:

1. **Month-Year**,
2. **Customer ID**,
3. **Number of Transactions in that month**.

---

I'm trying to create a table that has the output of 1. **Month-Year**, 2. **Number of churned customers in that month** defined as customers who have not had a transaction in the last 12 month. (So a customer would churn in Feb of 2015 if they only made one purchase in January of 2014.

If that person then has a transaction in March of 2015 but none until May 2016 then they've churned again in April of 2016).

I would appreciate any suggestions here.

---

The code I made works in `SQL` but not `Teradata`:

```
select 
month_start_date, 

    (select  1 
     from merchantengagement1 t2 
      where 
          t2.month_start_date >= t.month_start_date - INTERVAL '1' YEAR and
              t2.month_start_date < t.month_start_date and 
              transactions > 0  and 
              t.rcvr_ID = t2.rcvr_ID
    ) then 1 else 0 end) as churnedCustomers
from 
merchantengagement1  t
group by month_start_date
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your existing query will not run due to syntax errors (there's no CASE), otherwise it's valid in Teradata.

But there are two issues:

- never use `YEAR` or `MONTH` when adding intervals (it might result in an invalid date for end-of-months dates), use `ADD_MONTHS` instead.
- Correlated Subqueries like this are bad in all DBMSes, but especially bad in Teradata, resulting in product joins.

Your logic can be expressed using OLAP-functions, check if the following transaction is more than 12 months ahead or the latest transaction was more than 12 months ago:

```
SELECT rcvr_ID,
   -- if this date is before the next transaction it's a churn
   ADD_MONTHS(month_start_date, 12) AS churn_date
FROM merchantengagement1
WHERE transactions > 0
QUALIFY -- more than 12 months difference
   churn_date <
   COALESCE(MAX(month_start_date) -- next transaction
            OVER (PARTITION BY rcvr_ID
                  ORDER BY month_start_date
                  ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING)
           , CURRENT_DATE)        -- or today
```

Btw, there's no DBMS named `SQL` (of course, Microsoft tries to correlate it to their product)